# How to remember last selected radio value so that if I traverse the website 1 page forward and then go back, I can set a variable to remembered value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

As you can see in the code below, I have `type` set to `museum` by default, however, you can use the radio buttons to change the value of `type` to something else which triggers the watcher on `type` and makes a GET request which returns sights that belong to this `type`. You can then select any sight to be sent to a page that contains all the information about that sight.

Now here comes my problem. When I change the type by selecting a radio button, I get the new list of sights. Then if I click a sight and then decide to use the go back button, the `type` gets reset to `museum`. This is why I need to somehow remember the last selected radio value when I check a certain sight, so that when I go back, I could set the type to it.

Relevant part of code:

HTML used to change the value of `type`

```
<div>
<div class="radio">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="library" value="library" v-model="type">
        <label for="library">Libraries</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="park" value="park" v-model="type">
        <label for="park">Parks</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='sights-list'>
    <div class='sight' @click='selectSight(index)' v-for='(sight, index) in sights' v-if='sight.photos'>
        <p class='sight-name'>{{ sight.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/Vue

```
data(){
    return {
        sights: [],
        username: this.$route.params.username,
        city: this.$route.params.city,
        lat: this.$route.params.lat,
        lng: this.$route.params.lng,
        type: 'museum',
        range: 5000
    }
},
methods: {
    selectSight(index) {
        const placeId = this.sights[index].place_id;
        this.$router.push('/' + this.username + '/' + this.city + '/' + placeId)
    }
},
watch: {
    type: function () {
        axios.get('/getSights/' + this.lat + '/' + this.lng + '/' + this.type + '/' + this.range)
        .then(response => {
            this.sights = response.data.result.results
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `localStorage`
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage )

Comment: You can save your type in vuex, localStorage or even global variable (but avoid this) on route change [vue router - reacting to params changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes). And when user navigates back, you could read value back in `created` method